# Turn off onboard LEDs at boot

Tags: python, boot, board-leds, activity-led

I know very little about Raspberry Pi and Python. I've been able to turn off the LEDs in the terminal using the following command:

```
sudo su -
echo none > /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger
```

However, I would like to incorporate that into a Python program that can be executed on start-up. How can I approach this?

Answer (score 3):

I found a work around that simply allows me to add a few lines to the boot config file `/boot/config.txt`

To disable ACT LED, add

```
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
dtparam=act_led_activelow=off
```

To disable PWR LED, add

```
dtparam=pwr_led_trigger=none
dtparam=pwr_led_activelow=off
```

Comment: Please note that each of those lines is actually two lines

Comment: That may be a workaround but it's not a valid answer to your original question